# Oracle apex renaming uploading file

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I built form that upload files in oracle apex as blob. When I submit file I want to change file name by using any of plsql or JavaScript.

All files name are in table.

So I want to get the name from table and change uploading file.

Can you help me please?

Comment: instead of uploading to your own table, upload to APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES and then copy the data in your table with a page process. When copying the row, you can then manipulate the file name as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the utl_file.frename procedure. This procedure renames an existing file to a new name.
The documentation doesn't help much, but it might be worth checking it out: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-AE2D7739-9CD3-42EE-A3A5-29A7CAA70125

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE
  v_old_location VARCHAR2(100) := 'MY_DIR'; -- Directory where the file currently exists
  v_new_location VARCHAR2(100) := 'MY_NEW_DIR'; -- Directory where you want to move the file
  v_old_file_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'old_file.txt'; -- Name of the file you want to rename
  v_new_file_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'new_file.txt'; -- New name for the file
  
  v_file_exists BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
  -- Check if the old file exists
  v_file_exists := UTL_FILE.FGETATTR(location => v_old_location, filename => v_old_file_name) IS NOT NULL;
  
  IF v_file_exists THEN
    -- If the file exists, rename it
    UTL_FILE.FRENAME(
      src_location   => v_old_location,
      src_filename   => v_old_file_name,
      dest_location  => v_new_location,
      dest_filename  => v_new_file_name
    );
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File renamed successfully.');
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('File does not exist in the specified location.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: This only applies to files sitting on the database file server, not blobs within the database. Koen's inline response is applicable to files being loaded as a blob via a file-browse item.